# How to remove the space between parent table cell and the inner tables

Tags: html, css, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf and html tables to display data.

I want to put two html tables side by side in my pdf.

After some research, I realized (*in tcpdf*) I have to place two tables inside one parent table to get them side by side.

So, here is my code (I used inline css for demo purpose):

```
<table width="100%" style="border:1px solid #dddddd; border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0px;">
    <tr>
        <td width="30%" style="padding:0px; border-width:0px; margin:0px;">
            <table width="100%" style="border:1px solid #dddddd; border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0px; cell-margin:0px;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding:0px; border-width:0px; margin:0px;">Left-side table data</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td width="70%" style="padding:0px; border-width:0px; margin:0px;">
            <table width="100%" style="border:1px solid #dddddd; border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0px;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding:0px; border-width:0px; margin:0px;">Right-side table data</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

which results (in tcpdf) as follows:

[image: table result]

As you can see, there is a space on left-side of each child table.

I already tried padding:0px; border-width:0px; margin:0px; but not successful yet.

My question is "How to remove the space between parent table cell and the inner tables *when rendered in tcpdf*?".

**Note: there is no space when rendering as html but there is space when rendered in tcpdf.**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are no spacings here : https://onlinegdb.com/HkMoQD1aB

Comment: @tcadidot0 Yes, for html, there is no spacing. But, my problem is when rendered in tcpdf, the output is as shown in my image above. Thanks.

Comment: Opss.. sorry, I missed that

Comment: No problem, I also edited my question for clarification. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it. The problem is tcpdf rendering the space between `<td>` tag of parent table and `<table>` tag of child table.

```
 <table class="parent_table">
    <tr>
        <td>**<---- // tcpdf is rendering this space ------>**<table class="child_table"></table></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

When I eliminate the space between `<td>` tag of parent table and `<table>` tag of children table, the problem is solved.

Comment: You saved the day, was struggling on this since long

Answer (score 0):

I removed most of the spaces, but still there is space between the cell wall and table wall as shown in the image below
[image]

Any suggestions? Code is as below

```
<td style="width:100%;border-bottom:1px solid black;font-size: 10px;padding:0px; border-width:0px; margin:0px;"><table style="width:100%;; border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0px; cell-margin:0px;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th rowspan="2" style="border:1px solid black;">HSN/SAC</th>
                                                <th rowspan="2" style="border:1px solid black;">Taxable Value</th>
                                                <th colspan="2" style="border:1px solid black;">Central Tax</th>
                                                <th colspan="2" style="border:1px solid black;">Sales Tax</th>
                                                <th rowspan="2" style="border:1px solid black;">Total Tax Amount</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th style="border:1px solid black;">Rate</th>
                                                <th style="border:1px solid black;">Amount</th>
                                                <th style="border:1px solid black;">Rate</th>
                                                <th style="border:1px solid black;">Amount</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border:1px solid black;">1221212121</td>
                                                    <td style="border:1px solid black;">4,500.00</td>
                                                    <td style="border:1px solid black;">9%</td>
                                                    <td style="border:1px solid black;">405.00</td>
                                                    <td style="border:1px solid black;">9%</td>
                                                    <td style="border:1px solid black;">405.00</td>
                                                    <td style="border:1px solid black;">810.00</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border:1px solid black;text-align:right;">Total</td>
                                                    <td style="border:1px solid black;">4,500.00</td>
                                                    <td style="border:1px solid black;"></td>
                                                    <td style="border:1px solid black;">405.00</td>
                                                    <td style="border:1px solid black;">9%</td>
                                                    <td style="border:1px solid black;">405.00</td>
                                                    <td style="border:1px solid black;">810.00</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
```

Comment: I resolved this issue with removing padding:3px added to the main table, now I will have to set this with each TD/TR